# Using SUM() in oracle DB with reference from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation

I need a help with querying sum result with reference from another table
so I have two tables, MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED and FABRICATION

MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED,

```
HEAD_MARK SUBCONT_ID PROJECT_NAME
---------------------------------
HEADMARKA BOBBY      PROCESSHOUSE
HEADMARKB BOBBY      PROCESSHOUSE
HEADMARKC ERIC       PROCESSHOUSE
```

FABRICATION

```
HEAD_MARK CURRENT_WEIGHT PROJECT_NAME
-------------------------------------
HEADMARKA 19.5           PROCESSHOUSE
HEADMARKA 23.4           PROCESSHOUSE
HEADMARKA 11.2           PROCESSHOUSE
HEADMARKB 23.3           PROCESSHOUSE
HEADMARKB 10.9           PROCESSHOUSE
HEADMARKC 11.0           PROCESSHOUSE
HEADMARKC 10.5           PROCESSHOUSE
```

So at one day, I want to grab how much does BOBBY get for their total weight extracted from the current weight in FABRICATION. I find some hardtime on doing this. Please help me

my query is like this

```
SELECT SUM(CURRENT_WEIGHT)
       , MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.SUBCONT_ID 
FROM FABRICATION
     , MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED 
WHERE MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.HEAD_MARK = FABRICATION.HEAD_MARK
MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.PROJECT_NAME = 'PROCESSHOUSE' 
AND MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.SUBCONT_ID = 'BOBBY'
```

Comment: For future reference, reading the Oracle documentation with its examples will take the "hard" out of "hard time".  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have a typo and a missed `GROUP BY` clause. Also, you'd better use `JOIN` clauses and table aliases.

```
SELECT SUM(FABRICATION.CURRENT_WEIGHT),
       MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.SUBCONT_ID
FROM FABRICATION,
     MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED
WHERE MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.HEAD_MARK = FABRICATION.HEAD_MARK AND MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.PROJECT_NAME = 'PROCESSHOUSE'
  AND MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.SUBCONT_ID = 'BOBBY'
GROUP BY MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.SUBCONT_ID
```

Comment: [Why we should stop using old ANSI-89 JOIN syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum total weight of head marks:

```
select subcont_id, project_name, head_mark, total_weight
  from master_drawing_assigned m
  left join
      (select head_mark hm, sum(current_weight) total_weight
         from fabrication group by head_mark) f
  on m.head_mark=f.hm
  where subcont_id='BOBBY' order by head_mark;
```

And if you want to sum total weight of a project:

```
select subcont_id, project_name, sum(total_weight) total_weight
  from master_drawing_assigned m
  left join
      (select head_mark hm, sum(current_weight) total_weight
         from fabrication group by head_mark) f
  on m.head_mark=f.hm
  where subcont_id='BOBBY' group by subcont_id, project_name;
```

You can check results in **[this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea9f1/14)**